# Use of Func query

Tags: c#

I have the following segment of code but the x.PropertyThree has zero as the value although I can't work out how this segment of code is working to trace back where the property gets mapped.  Can you help explain what's happening here?  Where does x in x.PropertyThree come from?
Thanks,

**Code I'm struggling with**

```
        var data = DoSomething(
            model,
            options,
            x => x.KeyDisplayValue,
            (x, s) => new List<object>
                                    {
                                        Magic(x.PropertyOne, s),
                                        Magic(x.PropertyTwo, s),
                                        Magic(x.PropertyThree, s),
                                        x.PropertyFour,
                                        x.PropertyFive,
                                        x.NoOperationRate,
                                     });
```

**Method**

```
protected List<List<object>> DoSomething(
        MyModel model,
        MyOptions options,
        Func<TSomething,string> theValue,
        Func<TSomething, bool, List<object>> aMethod)
```

Comment: You could do with showing the method body for 'DoSomething'.

Comment: What is your question?  That `x` is the same as in the `(x, s)` arguments passed into the anonymous function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(x, s) => new List<object>
                                    {
                                        Magic(x.PropertyOne, s),
                                        Magic(x.PropertyTwo, s),
                                        Magic(x.PropertyThree, s),
                                        x.PropertyFour,
                                        x.PropertyFive,
                                        x.NoOperationRate,
                                     }
```

is a lambda expression, it can be translated to method:

```
public List<object> unnamed(TSomething x, bool s) {
   return new List<object>
                                        {
                                            Magic(x.PropertyOne, s),
                                            Magic(x.PropertyTwo, s),
                                            Magic(x.PropertyThree, s),
                                            x.PropertyFour,
                                            x.PropertyFive,
                                            x.NoOperationRate,
                                         };
}
```

`new List<object> { ... }` is just a shortcut to:

```
var list = new List<object>();
list.Add(Magic(x.PropertyOne, s));
list.Add(Magic(x.PropertyTwo, s));
...
list.Add(x.NoOperationRate);
```

Inside `DoSomething` method must be a code:

```
aMethod(something, someBool);
```

in other words you should look inside `DoSomething` function to find out what parameters are passed to this long lambda.

Comment: where does PropertyThree come from?  Obviously it's a property on the x object but I'm not understanding where it comes from

Comment: @Jamie since `DoSomething` is not generic method then class containing `DoSomething` must be generic and must have `TSomething` parameter in its declaraction e.g. `class Foo<TSomething> { void DoSomething() { } }`